# How to remove a custom view from list view using a button in the custom view

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I created a custom view with a edit text field and a button. I want to delete an item from listview by clicking on a button.
The code for the custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"
        android:id="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/player_name_txt"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:editable="false"
        android:background="#5eb8ed"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete_btn"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/delete_btn" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

The code for the adapter and list view:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    playerListView = (ListView)this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView().findViewById(R.id.player_list);
    playerListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.player_item,R.id.player_name_txt, new ArrayList<String>(){});
playerListView.setAdapter(playerListAdapter);
```

The Code I tried:

```
 public void removePlayer(View v)
    {
        EditText pairedEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.player_name_txt);
        String name = pairedEdit.getText().toString();
        playerListAdapter.remove(name);
        playerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Right now it removes the first item in the list view.

```
AlertDialog.Builder addPlayerBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_player,null);
        final EditText usernameEdit = (EditText)customView.findViewById(R.id.username_edit);
        addPlayerBuilder.setView(customView);
        addPlayerBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                String name = usernameEdit.getText().toString();
                playerListAdapter.add(name);
                playerListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        addPlayerBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = addPlayerBuilder.create();
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: you need to remove the selected item by it's position

Comment: You could give both elements a tag with their respective resoure ids as the key and remove the other element when the button is clicked by adding an onclick attribute or an onclicklistener.  Set the visibility to gone or invisible.

Answer (score 1):

In your button of custom layout place a **onclicklistener** which would remove the element from the arraylist by **remove**() function on the basis of its position and then call **notifyDataSetInvalidated**()

Comment: How do I find the position of the custom view? because all the view will have the same id correct?

Comment: In your adapter class u would be using a function View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) which has position as its parameter which you should use.

Comment: I understand that I need the position to remove the item, but I do not know how to get the actual position of the custom view the button is apart of. How do I go about getting the position of the view?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Button b2 = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2.setTag(arg0); 
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                int pos = (int)arg0.getTag();
                  lista.remove(pos);
                  SunetePreferateAdaptor.this.notifyDataSetChanged();            }
        });
```

Comment: How do I find the position of the custom view? because all the view will have the same id correct?

Comment: yes, but how do I find the position of the custom view the button that was clicked is apart of?

Comment: I am confused as to what row is and what arg0 is. If I know the row I also know the position because they are the same.

Comment: It is just the regular ArrayAdapter class here is the code I use to add things to the adapter above however

Answer (score 0):

In adapter class on delete_btn click you have to call remove method :

```
 public class yourAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Activity context;
    private ArrayList<yourBean> arrList;

    public yourAdapter(Activity context,
            ArrayList<yourBean> arrList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrList = arrList;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return arrList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,
                    null);


            viewHolder.delete_btn= (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);


            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.delete_btn.setTag(position);


        viewHolder.delete_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                    arrayList.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        Button delete_btn;
    }

}
```

Comment: How do I find the position of the custom view? because all the view will have the same id correct?

Comment: you have to right the above code in getview method of your adapter class for example : public 'View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {}'

Comment: your get view method still ask for a position variable if i knew the position i could just do .remove(position) i need to know how to get the position of the clicked delete button

Comment: when you click on any listitem delete button from listview then it will take that list item position from getview method, you just need to pass that position in remove method

Comment: What am I calling get view on?

Comment: for that you have to create custom adapter class extending baseadapter for listview and from that you can get listview item position from getView method

Comment: How does that work? Could you edit your answer for it please?